# PHP - Increment Dates in Loop

Tags: php, date

```
$end_date = new DateTime($_GET['end_date']); 
$last_day_this_month = $end_date->format('d-m-Y'); //outputs 10-03-2015

$start_date = new DateTime($_GET['start_date']);
$loop_dates = $start_date->format('d-m-Y'); //outputs 22-04-2015

        for($i = $loop_dates; $i <= $last_day_this_month; $i++)
        {
                echo $i;echo '<br>';


        }
```

Using below loop increments the year and not dates

```
for($i = $loop_dates; $i <= $last_day_this_month; $i++)
```

How could I traverse/increment through start/end dates using loop so that it outputs all the dates from `10-03-2015` to `22-04-2015`.

P.S: I am using `PHP5.3` and so want to go with object oriented approach instead of using strtotime

Comment: Have you considered [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php)?

Comment: calculate number of days between these two dates and apply `$date->modify('+1 day');` change `+1` with `$i`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try below code

```
$begin = new DateTime('2013-02-01');
$end = new DateTime('2013-02-13');

$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);

foreach($daterange as $date){
    echo $date->format("d") . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: It outputs `10-20` and not specifically from `10-MAR to 20-APR`

Answer (score 3):

> Try this one

```
<?php
$start = '2013-08-25';
$end = '2013-08-29';
$datediff = strtotime($end) - strtotime($start);
$datediff = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
for($i = 0; $i < $datediff + 1; $i++){
    echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start . ' + ' . $i . 'day')) . "<br>";
}
?>
```