# Codeigniter-PHP : How to Change table week Dates , On change of input date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

```
<input type = "date" name = "myDate" onchange = ""> //this is input date
```

When the user picks a date then it wants to change based on above date
How to change based on given date please help me..!

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="thbg">

<thead><td></td>

<th>Project</th>

<th>Activity</th>

<th>Bill Type</th>

<?php

$day = "1";
$month = "11";
$year = "2017";

$start_date = $day."-".$month."-".$year;
$start_time = strtotime($start_date);

$end_time = strtotime("+1 week", $start_time);

for($i=$start_time; $i<$end_time; $i+=86400)
{
  print  '<th align="center"> '. date("m-d-Y  l", $i). '</th>';
}
?>
<th>Hours</th>      
</thead>
</table>
```

And the output is also getting wrong dates, e.g. I am getting two Sundays at a time

[image: this is my wrong output]

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Just a comment - your HTML is technically invalid. You should have a `<tr>` around all your `<td>`s and `<th>`s - i.e. table cells must be within a table row, which can itself be within a `<thead>` or `<tbody>`, and those must be within a `<table>` element.

Comment: Yaa i changed my code with <table>, but this is not my solution

Comment: I know it's not, that's why I made it a comment not an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you try to achieve here but a better option would be to use the `DateTime` Class

something like that should work

```
$day = "1";
$month = "11";
$year = "2017";
$objDateStart = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('j-m-Y', $day."-".$month."-".$year);
$objDateEnd = $objDateStart->modify('+1 week');

$objDateRange = new DatePeriod($objDateStart, new DateInterval('P1D'), $objDateEnd);
foreach($objDateRange as $objDate)
{
    echo  '<th align="center"> '. $objDate->format("m-d-Y l"). '</th>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
As it is i have executed your code, i am getting proper output without any repeated values. 

echo "<table><thead>

        <th>Project</th>

        <th>Activity</th>

        <th>Bill Type</th>";


        $day = "1";
        $month = "11";
        $year = "2017";

        $start_date = $day."-".$month."-".$year;
        $start_time = strtotime($start_date);

        $end_time = strtotime("+1 week", $start_time);

        for($i=$start_time; $i<$end_time; $i+=86400)
        {
          print   '<th align="center"> '. date("m-d-Y  l", $i). '</th>';
        }
        echo "<th>Hours</th>
        </thead>";
```

Comment: but iam getting like this:                                                                                    11-01-2017 Wednesday 11-02-2017 Thursday 11-03-2017 Friday 11-04-2017 Saturday 11-05-2017 Sunday 11-05-2017 Sunday 11-06-2017 Monday 11-07-2017 Tuesday

Comment: i got two sundays at a time

Comment: if it is possible please try to post full code... then we can find the mistake. As of now what i have posted with code that is working fine. have you tried my code?

Comment: please see my picture above

Answer (score 0):

The `date` command is repeating Nov 5th because that was daylight saving time and it's rounding down the hours to 00:00:00.

Try using the `datetime` object instead.

Here's an answer that loops through a date range with it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29765247/3585500